# Estimate a state space model by using linear multiple regression?

Tags: matrices, matlab, parameter-estimation, optimal-control, linear-regression

Let's say that I want to model this state space model:
$$\dot{x}(t) = Ax(t) + Bu(t)$$
$$y(t) = Cx(t) + Du(t)$$

But I know $x(t), u(t)$ and not $A, B, C, D$.

Can I then use multiple linear regression to estimate(curve fit) the state space model?

If you don't know what multiple linear regression is: Look here:
https://youtu.be/qdOG7YMolmA?t=4m9s

Comment: Three functions $x,u,y$? Don't you usually have two functions and their derivatives expressed as linear combinations of them? Like second equation replaced by $\dot u(t) = Cx(t) + Du(t)$

Comment: No. I just know the states over time and input over time. I think that's enough to estimate a state space model. But I have not seen anyone do that. I have only seen people estimate transfer functions from ARX/ARMAX models.

Comment: You would need a 'sufficiently rich' set of $x, u$ presumably to identify all modes of the system. Do you know the order of the system?

Comment: Well. It's allways second order in industrial systems. I have read about tools named N4SID and MOESP. These tools can estimate a state space model.  Problem is that I cannot find any information about them. I can see that N4SID and MOESP using a Hankel matrix for some reason.